# Decode JSON in android

Tags: android, json

I have a problem with getting decoded string from JSON. I am connected with web service and get JSON: `{"pdf":"JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKNyAwIG9iaiAKPDwKL0ZpbHRlciAvRmxhdGVE...` 
this is string but encoded in Base64. I try decode that using:

```
                JSONObject jsonMap = new JSONObject(out.toString());
                String json =jsonMap.getJSONObject("pdf").toString();
                byte temp[];
                Base64 b = null;

                temp = b.decode(json.getBytes(), 0);
```

but this solution doesn't work. Any ideas?
This is error log:

```
11-12 14:36:30.257: W/System.err(12374): org.json.JSONException: Value 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
11-12 14:36:30.257: W/System.err(12374):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
11-12 14:36:30.257: W/System.err(12374):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:573)
11-12 14:36:30.257: W/System.err(12374):    at pdf2app.models.Magazine.<init>(Magazine.java:74)
11-12 14:36:30.257: W/System.err(12374):    at pdf2app.activities.DownloaderService.parsePdfs(DownloaderService.java:490)
11-12 14:36:30.257: W/System.err(12374):    at pdf2app.activities.DownloaderService.getPDFs(DownloaderService.java:416)
11-12 14:36:30.257: W/System.err(12374):    at pdf2app.activities.DownloaderService.onHandleIntent(DownloaderService.java:183)
11-12 14:36:30.257: W/System.err(12374):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
11-12 14:36:30.257: W/System.err(12374):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-12 14:36:30.257: W/System.err(12374):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

This is out.toString():

```
11-12 14:27:37.027: V/Loggggg(12308): {"pdf":"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
```

it is looks like problem is in line :`String json =jsonMap.getJSONObject("pdf").toString();` because in debugger after that line I get error

Comment: `but this solution doesn't work.` is not a clear information. error message, would be better. Also, If that is your text, then that is not a JSON string. JSON require either `[]` or `{}` as wrapper.

Comment: As you can see it has a wrapper "{}" inside his `out.toString(); `Besides he has posted enough errorlog information with it. And according to one of the answers, it seems like the JSONException that occured is stating that the type of value your retrieving isn't the same type as you specify it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the parsing is wrong

```
            JSONObject jsonMap = new JSONObject(out.toString());
            String json =jsonMap.getString("pdf");
```

And then do the base64 decode.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `jsonMap.getJSONObject("pdf")` you should use `jsonMap.getString("pdf")`